# Parse Sever with custom Express app Master Key Permission Denied

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

We have a custom express app that loads in the node.js parse server sdk.  When we try to use a function call that requires the master key we keep getting errors for permission denied.

```
    at /Users/gateway/Documents/lm/Website/lm-node/node_modules/parse/lib/node/RESTController.js:324:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)
(node:61092) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
(node:61092) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

we initiate our parse server like this..

```
Parse.initialize(process.env.PARSE_STAGING_APP_ID, null, process.env.PARSE_STAGING_MASTER_KEY);
//Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
Parse.serverURL = process.env.PARSE_STAGING_SERVER_URL;
Parse.User.enableUnsafeCurrentUser();

module.exports = Parse
```

```
async function channelStatus(orgId) {

  const Status = Parse.Object.extend("Status");
  const query = new Parse.Query(Status);
  query.equalTo("orgID", orgId);

  try {
    const results = await query.first({useMasterKey: true});

    if(results) {
      // do some stuff
      results.save();

    } else {
      const StatusNew = Parse.Object.extend("Status");
      const statusNew = new StatusNew();
      // do some stuff
      statusNew.save() 
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

if we enable Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); it works but this can be bad because it works for every function.. we want to make sure we are using masterKey on certain functions..

thoughts?

full error in visual studio.

```
(node:35145) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Permission denied for action get on class Status.
    at /Users/gateway/Documents/lmx/WebSite/lmx/node_modules/parse/lib/node/RESTController.js:324:19
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:35145) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
(node:35145) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
GET /test - - ms - -
```

Logs

```
Jul 29 13:08:29 lmx-stage app/web.1: error: Error generating response. ParseError { 
Jul 29 13:08:29 lmx-stage app/web.1:   code: 119, 
Jul 29 13:08:29 lmx-stage app/web.1:   message: 'Permission denied for action get on class Status.' } code=119, message=Permission denied for action get on class Status. 
Jul 29 13:08:29 lmx-stage app/web.1: error: Permission denied for action get on class Status. code=119, message=Permission denied for action get on class Status.
```

Comment: Can you please confirm that you are requiring parse like this `const Parse = require('parse/node');`? And also share the complete error stack with the error message?

Comment: Can you please also confirm that the line that is throwing the error is this one here `const results = await query.first({useMasterKey: true});`?

Comment: I forgot to past the line for require.. var Parse = require('parse/node');

Comment: @DaviMacêdo yea.. i broke it down to the bare bones and yes thats the line that throws.

Comment: Can you please share the complete error stack, including the error message that you see in your logs?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo updated above.. this is really odd.. I have no issues with this in php when dealing with a query that requires master user.

Comment: Can you please try to comment this line here `Parse.User.enableUnsafeCurrentUser();` ? You should not use current user in a Node.js environment. I think that the SDK is sending a session token together with the master key and the parse server is trying to validate the permissions for this session token regardless the master key.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo yea I tried that same result.. this is so odd, im not sure even how to track this down to see why it's throwing the error..

Comment: I've just seen you talked about `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()`. Is it a cloud code function? Or an Express.js application? Would you be able to share more of the code? How you are requiring Parse, mounting the router, etc?

Comment: I found (https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/413) this about ```Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()``` this seems to allow any query to use the master key, of course should only be used serve side.  Our app is a custom express that we are building.

Comment: Just to make sure, if you change your CLP to allow all public permissions for class Status, does it work?

Comment: very odd.. this function `const results = await query.first({useMasterKey: true});` doesn't work.. if you use `const results = await query.find({useMasterKey: true});`  .. so first doesn't seem to work, but find does.. ?? lol.. seems like a bug.

Comment: Both should work. Can you please confirm what is the SDK version that you are using?

Comment: 2.6.0 ... tested the query again.. simply changing `const results = await query.first({useMasterKey: true});` to `const results = await query.find({useMasterKey: true});` works.. so for now we just dont use first..

Comment: It seems to be a bug that should be fixed. Do you mind to open an issue in the JS SDK repo?

Comment: Yea.. Ill do that in a bit.. been a bit crazy with work.. seems like a batch save all might be also having similar issues..